# Troubleshooting TensorFlow Model Deployment in Docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

In my current project, I'm working on deploying a Flask API within a Docker container, which is designed to interface with a TensorFlow model. For this setup, I've opted to use the tensorflow/tensorflow:latest Docker image, which should theoretically provide the most up-to-date features and optimizations available for TensorFlow.

However, during the deployment process, I'm encountering a significant hurdle. As the Docker container attempts to install the Python dependencies specified in my requirements file, it fails, halting the deployment. This issue is quite perplexing and could be attributed to a variety of factors.

<--- Dockerfile --->

`FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest`

**Set a directory for the app**

`WORKDIR /usr/src/app`

**Install dependencies**

`COPY requirements.txt ./`

`RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`

**Copy the current directory contents into the container**

`COPY . .`

**Make port 5000 available to the world outside this container**

`EXPOSE 8000`

**Define environment variable**

`ENV NAME World`

**Run app.py when the container launches**

`CMD ["python", "app.py"]`

<-- Error Message -->

**Terminal Command**

```
docker build -t tensorflow-model-app .
```

> ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Comment: The error you are facing shows that the pip install command you are using in dockerfile is failing. This could be due to various reasons incorrect dependencies in your requirements.txt file